# C String assignment backwards

Tags: c

I have some decompiled C source code and saw this strange string assignment.

```
char v1[21];
v1[0] = 0x75767778;
"tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba" = v1;
```

What is going on? How is this possible?

Comment: this should not work on compiling. The left side of the assignment should always be a variable. Therer might be an issue with the decompilation.

Comment: I got this from https://retdec.com/decompilation/

Comment: Note that `0x75767778` is the hex ascii sequence for "uvwx" (or maybe "xwvu"). That assignment could probably work in assembly, but the other one is incomprehensible. Anyway, could it just be a bug in the decompiler?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the decompiler. It generates code that is not valid C (or even sensible).

Comment: You say you got it from retdec. Do you have the original source code, too? Post it.

Comment: Fully decompiling is not possible for every exe ;)

Comment: Please update the question to indicate how you "decompiled" this.

Comment: Where did 'y' and 'z' go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char v1[21];
```

No problem so far; that defines `v1` as an array of 21 `char` elements.

```
v1[0] = 0x75767778;
```

Legal, but incorrect. `v1[0]` is a `char` object. Unless `CHAR_BIT >= 32` (which is unlikely), it cannot hold the value `0x75767778`. If plain `char` is unsigned and `CHAR_BIT==8`, it would assign the value `0x78`; if plain `char` is signed, it will *probably* do the same, but the value is implementation-defined.

It might be relevant that the bytes of `0x75767778` are the ASCII codes for the characters `'u'`, `'v'`, `'w'`, and `'x'`.

```
"tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba" = v1;
```

This is simply illegal. A string literal cannot be the left hand side of an assignment and C does not support array assignment.

Apparently your "decompiler" (which you haven't identified) is generating something that more or less looks like C, but isn't.

This might be *partly* explained if the left and right sides of the assignments are being reversed. Even if that's the case, the output appears to be some sort of pseudo-code. (Did the code actually use `=` rather than, say, `->` or `=>`?)

Seeing the source code from which this was "decompiled" would be helpful -- as would knowing what "decompiler" you're using and seeing its documentation.

My *guess* is that the source code had a string literal like `"xwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"`, and that generated code used an integer assignment to copy `"xwvu"` (represented as `0x75767778`) and a separate operation for the remaining 20 characters, but that's only a guess. Or perhaps it was `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"` and it was reversed due to byte ordering.